# Used to, but can no longer access files in gvfs from outside nautilus

Tags: linux, samba, shared-folders

I have a shared windows server mounted on

`/run/usr/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=server.urlend,share=someshare`

I used to have the ability to acces files on here. I can still browse the directory from nautilus, but not from the terminal, when trying to run `ls` in `/run/usr/1000/gvfs/` I get the error

```
ls: cannot access 'smb-share:server=server.urlend,share=someshare': Input/output error
'smb-share:server.urlend,share=someshare'
```

The last line (`'smb-share:server.urlend,share=someshare'`) is not in normal text color (I don't know if that information holds any value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the *gvfsd-fuse* daemon is having some problems (which exports the GVFS mounts to `/run/user`). Meanwhile Nautilus talks directly to the GVFS core daemons and doesn't rely on the FUSE interface.

It would be easiest to `pkill gvfs` and re-login.

Depending on distribution you can also try `systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon`.

---

If you want to attempt a manual cleanup, first remove the existing mount (either method works):

```
$ fusermount -u /run/user/1000/gvfs
$ sudo umount /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

Then either manually start the FUSE daemon...

```
$ (setsid /usr/lib/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes &)
```

...or try to restart all the GVFS services:

```
$ systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ;-). When trying to run either of the unmount commands I get a mount is busy error. The `systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon` command worked great. I've done that (So I can no longer test why the unmounts gave error messages)

Comment: Still an issue on Lunar... Couldn't fix that until tried to `fusermount -u /run/user/1000/gvfs`. Thanks!